# Hide option in select with div

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to hide a option in select with div, and then use `style.display = "none"`

Html code I have used:

```
<div class="test">
    <div class="optioncheck" id="text place">
        <select id="status" onChange="myFunction()">
            <option value="1">Texts</option>
            <div class="options" id="text"><option value="2">Text</option></div>
            <div class="options" id="text1"><option value="3">Text1</option></div>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="optioncheck" id="map" style="display:none;">
        Text
        <div class="optioncheck" id="map1" style="display:none;">
            Text
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript I try to use to hide the options if variable is false

```
var readtext = false;

if (readtext == true) {
     document.getElementById('text').style.display = "block";
} else {
     document.getElementById('text').style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: Why are you using divs even the option can be made hidden with simple css?

Comment: You can't hide it with css, instead you should rather remove and add the options with your js code, by storing them in an array/object.

Comment: Are you trying to hide some items in select?

Comment: question is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly. Instead, you have to use (or write) javascript library which will demonstrate divs for select options. Just like Select2 jQuery library does.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `display:none` for hiding options in select, if you want to hide option you can use something like

`$( "#status option[value=1]" ).wrap( "<span>" );`

and to again show the particular option use

`if ( $( "#status option[value=2]" ).parent().is( "span" ) ){
    $( "#status option[value=2]" ).unwrap();
}`

This should do the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

## **Remove divs, use just options.**

Here your code without divs.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ryOeWo

```
<div class="test">
    <div class="optioncheck" id="text place">
        <select id="status" onChange="myFunction()">
          <option value="1">Texts </option>
          <option id="text" value="2">Text</option>
          <option value="3">Text1</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="optioncheck" id="map" style="display:none;">
       Text
    <div class="optioncheck" id="map1" style="display:none;">
       Text
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just wish to hide some options other than the first option.You can do that via simple javascript.
Refer to this fiddle:
    https://jsfiddle.net/ysd8w8sk/ 
Let's say we have following html:

```
<select id="fruits_dropdown">
<option value='1' > Apple </option>
<option value ='2'> Banana </option>
<option value ='3'> Orange </option>
<option value ='4'> Cherry </option>
</select>
```

Then we can hide option 2 and 3 like this :

```
document.querySelector('#fruits_dropdown option[ value="2"]').style.display='None';
document.querySelector('#fruits_dropdown option[ value="3"]').style.display='None';
```

Comment: If you look at the output in jsfiddle, you will see only 2 options whereas there were suppose to be 4 options to be visible. I just verified it again @SuitGames